# Nesting functions in PHP

Tags: php

Simple PHP question:

Why does this work,

```
$exclude_exts = array('js', 'css',);
$filename = "test.css";
$ext = explode('.',$filename);
$is_excluded = in_array(strtolower(array_pop($ext)), $exclude_exts);
```

but this doesn't.

```
$exclude_exts = array('js', 'css',);
$filename = "test.css";
$is_excluded = in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename))), $exclude_exts);
```

Edit: Both used to work in a previous version of PHP (I forgot which version).

Answer (score 10):

Because [array_pop](https://www.php.net/array_pop) requires a reference, since it alters the array in place.
When you pass the return value of `explode` there is no variable there to reference.

Comment: @Ameer It didn't work in previous versions of PHP. It has never worked.

Comment: @Ameer I do not think it worked. It might not have crashed with a fatal, but probably it was shaky at best. PHP5.4 introduced some stricter checking for these types of issues (which is good!) and that's probably what you're experiencing.

Comment: Currently testing to see whether it has ever worked in previous versions - http://3v4l.org/4I9Xh#tabs - looks like it worked prior to PHP 5.0.5; but has thrown a strict standards warning since then

Comment: Yes, I am damn sure it worked in a previous version. This was the ONLY issue with my code when my host upgraded to PHP 5.4